# Using "of" before two nouns

Tags: prepositions, nouns

Example: a quotient of number a and number b. Is it correct or "of" works only for "number a" and not for all "number a and number b"?
More accurate, I think, is "a quotient of a division of number a and number b". But is the first example correct?
Or maybe another "of" is needed here?

Comment: I think this is ambiguous, or could be confusing, depending on what you mean. You should consider rewording it if you want to separate "the quotient of number a", from "number b" entirely.  Try this instead: "number b, and a quotient of number a". Or perhaps you mean "a quotient of number a divided by number b". What do you actually mean to say?

Comment: The word "quotient" generally takes two arguments, so this would generally be understood as a ÷ b. Similarly, if you said "the wedding of Orsino and Viola", people would assume there was only one marriage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a quotient of number a and number b" is correct. This is understood to be *one* quotient of *two* numbers, not "a quotient of number a" and "number b".

A case where it *is* ambiguous would be "the square root of number a and number b" - that could mean either √a + b or √(a+b).

"a quotient of a division of number a and number b" is not, because the quotient is the *result* of the division of number a *by* number b.